# Problems opening javascript github examples

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, dc.js

So I want to start using dc.js package to create a few dashboards, and I've found this tutorial:

https://github.com/austinlyons/dcjs-leaflet-untappd

I've downloaded the entire folder and attempted to open the html to see whether it works, but I only get some parts of the page (no data, no graphs, you can see the expected and gotten image attached). I've had the same problem with some other tutorials that I've found, and can't figure out why. I can open the page in the browser when it is a link like:

https://austinlyons.github.io/dcjs-leaflet-untappd/

Any ideas? I am using Chrome btw, but it doesn't work in IE either.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to run it on a web server to test it out, as stated by the [README](https://github.com/austinlyons/dcjs-leaflet-untappd#try-it-yourself).

Comment: Ok, but why can I for instance run the same webpage if I save it from the internet as .html ?

Comment: Because the webpage you're saving has already downloaded all the data it needs and rendered the page. When you run the project from the filesystem, the browser's security restrictions block the data downloads.

Comment: Thank you both, I am still learning this stuff! :)

Comment: But I am just wondering, data downloads? The data is saved in a JSON that is attached, only a map is being downloaded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone is interested there is a very nice workaround for those not willing to play around with a server. For some reason Firefox allows the opening of such pages, so one can test D3 and similar code in it without having to run a server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in your terminal.

> **Try it yourself**
>
> If you want to play with the code as we go, I recommend downloading
>   the source code from this GitHub repository, navigating to the
>   directory where the files are located, and kicking off Python's
>   SimpleHTTP server so that you can see your visualization in your own
>   browser at http://localhost:8000 (If this is new for you, see [this
>   link](https://github.com/lmccart/itp-creative-js/wiki/SimpleHTTPServer) for a bit more information).